# Manim says GraphScene does not exist

Tags: python, math, graph, manim

I have just started using manim, however when I try to draw a graph it gives me the following error: "NameError: name 'GraphScene' is not defined"

my code is listed here:

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class graphx(GraphScene):
    CONFIG={
        "x_min":-4,
        "x_max":4,
        "x_axis_label":"$x$",
        "y_axis_label":"$y$"
    }

    def show_function_graph(self):
        self.setup_axis(animate=True)
        def func(x):
            return ((x+1)//2)**x
        graph=self.get_graph(func,x_min=-1,x_max=1)
        self.play(ShowCreation(graph))

    def construct(self):
        self.show_function_graph()

#manim -pql newmanim.py graphx
```

sidenote: I'm following a youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GemuXCUEBVU